# Find out, that the touch position is in Imageview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i try to run some code, when my finger is moved to the same position, where the imageview is.

I defined the position of the image view:

```
CGRect imagepos = myImage.frame;
```

And the position of actual touch position:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self.view];
```

I tried with`CGPointEqualToPoint` it not worked. Then i tried with `CGRectContainsPoint` it also not worked, because, when imagepos and currentpos have the same x coordinates, my "some code" is running (my finger is not moved to the image, they had only the same x positions. Y positions are totally different).

How can I say, when my finger (also in the method touchesmoved) touch/is moved to/is at anywhere of the image, run some code or a method?

Thanks for Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your touchesBegan method, you can try something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch view] == myImgView)
    {
        NSLog(@"My Image was touched");
    }
}
```

This tells you when your ImageView is touched. Make sure you set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES in your imageView.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, i tried, but it doesnt work because, my images are spritenodes. I got the warning: Comparison of distinct pointer types 'UIVIEW' and 'SKSpriteNode'.

Comment: @Mehmet63 do you not think it would have been a good idea to mention sprites or sprite kit in your question? Instead of the word "Imageview" which is a UIKit object.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes U are right. That was a failure. I am trying the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try out below -

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];  //Now you got current location of click or tap

    if(location.y == YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW_POSITION_Y)
    {
      NSLog(@"Got the TOUCH...OOOoopsss !!!");
    }   
  }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function...

```
CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
```

It returns a bool if the point is inside the rect.

So get the touch point and run this with the imageView frame to find out if the touch was inside the image view.